# Using VMWareTasks without installing VIX API

Tags: c#, .net, api, vmware, vmwaretasks

I am using VMWareTasks for some time, and i was always wondering if it is possible to use it without installing the VIX API.

The VIX API is a pretty big install (over 100 MB), our app is barely 10 MB of install size.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the VIX API at all, but according to their GitHub repo documentation (section [**Prerequisites**](https://github.com/dblock/vmwaretasks#prerequisites)):

> ### Prerequisites
>
> In order to use the library you must install the following VMWare software.
>
> - **VMWare VIX.** This is the SDK, obtained from http://www.vmware.com/download/sdk/vmauto.html. Version 1.6.2 or newer is required for VI support. Version 1.8.0 or newer is required for VMWare Player support.
> - Either VMWare Workstation 6.5.2, 7.0, 7.1 or later, VMWare Server 2.0, VMWare Player 3.0 or 3.1, a Virtual Infrastructure environment (eg. ESXi) or VSphere 4.0 or 4.1.